# Concatenating multiple lists in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, scala-collections, tail-recursion

I have a function called generateList and concat function as follows. It is essentially concatenating lists returned by the generateList with i starting at 24 and ending at 1

```
 def concat(i: Int, l: List[(String, Int)]) : List[(String, Int)] = {
          if (i==1) l else l ::: concat(i-1, generateList(signs, i))
 }
 val all = concat(23, generateList(signs, 24))
```

I can convert this to tail-recursion. But I am curious if there a scala way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this with Scala's built in methods available to Lists.

Here is one approach that uses foldRight

```
(1 to 24).foldRight(List[Int]())( (i, l) => l ::: generateList(i))
```

Starting with the range of ints you use to build separate lists, it concats the result of generateList(i) to the initial empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this:

```
val signs = ""
def generateList(s: String, n: Int) = n :: n * 2 :: Nil


scala> (24 to 1 by -1) flatMap (generateList(signs, _))
res2: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(24, 48, 23, 46, 22, 44, 21, 42, 20, 40, 19, 38, 18, 36, 17, 34, 16, 32, 15, 30, 14, 28, 13, 26, 12, 24, 11, 22, 10, 20, 9, 18, 8, 16, 7, 14, 6, 12, 5, 10, 4, 8, 3, 6, 2, 4, 1, 2)
```

What you want to do is to map the list with `x => generateList(signs, x)` function and then concatenate the results, i.e. flatten the list. This is just what `flatMap` does.